# How to auto submit a JavaScript web form in some website using cusom form data?

Tags: javascript, forms, automation

I would like to see if this is possible. I go to a website and find some signup page. I want to fill it with my data and submit it. The form is not directly written on the web page, but is appended / loaded using some JavaScript. What I want is I want to do this without using my browser, like using some tools / script. [Here](https://www.myntra.com/register?referer=https://www.myntra.com/) is an example page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This has been made by passing data to the server via the URL. If you are interested in passing data in through the server, you should learn [node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8XF6AFGqlc). With node.js you can run code based on the URL.

The main idea is that this is somewhat server side (or node.js). Learning node.js will reveal some ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks @SciRanch so it will be like "GET" method, where the target url will contain all the payload, am i right?

Comment: Yes. It is not exactly a GET because node.js has its own way of checking the URL, but that is similar to how it works.